# CSS: Font Problem - Ubuntu Condensed Font doesn't render correctly sometimes

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, fonts, stylesheet

i despair with the following problem for a few weeks now:

I have a stylesheet where i import the "Ubuntu Condensed" Font at the beginning:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed");
```

After that i apply it on the body, this way:

```
body {
font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

Now the Problem/Bug(?) comes in .. sometimes (like on every 10-30 page visit) the "Ubuntu Condensed" Font seems to not render correctly (see Screenshot). The lettertype looks completly buggy at the whole page (body) then!

[Screenshot of the Problem (wrong VS correct font representation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHEFS.png)

After i hit Strg + F5 the problem disappears, til i visit the page again some times.

I've used this font in a other project before and never had this kind of problem.. :( Any ideas?

Thanks a lot! :)

Greetings
- Zomboid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real solution but a workaround: consider using [google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts). This way you're hosting the fonts yourself. Selfhosting will also render the fonts a tiny bit quicker then getting them from https://fonts.googleapis.com/.

Comment: I will try this out (may it helps). -> Thank you! :)

Comment: That seems like it fixed the problem! +rep